# Are there any chemicals that combine readily with oxygen?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I am designing an industrial process which can remove oxygen from air.
This chemical should combine readily with oxygen in the presence of heat.

In particular, I am looking for a chemical with the following properties:

1. Combines readily with oxygen, thus removing the oxygen in air
2. Inexpensive
3. Environmentally friendly (nontoxic)

For point #1, heating is available if it is an endothermic reaction.

I am looking at at an operating temperature of ~$\pu{800 ^\circ C}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrogallol for example

Comment: Pyrogallol is way too toxic

Comment: *At what temperature?* Carbon or magnesium would remove oxygen at 1,000 K or higher. Alkaline glucose might be used at room temperature, though it reacts slowly (see http://faculty.mansfield.edu/bganong/biochemistry/bluebott.htm). More information would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If $\ce{CO2}$ is acceptable in the feed gas, along with $\ce{CO}$ and a bit of left-over oxygen, then carbon (coal, charcoal etc.) might do. [It's ignition temperature is ~1,000 K.](http://www.safetystoragecentre.co.uk/advice/Auto-Ignition-Temperature-5.html)

Magnesium is more expensive, but leaves less oxygen and has no gaseous byproduct. [It's self-ignition temperature is ~800 K.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium)

Many other materials could be used; *it really depends on how the gas is to be used*.

Comment: What about just releasing the gas into the atmosphere?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of your process.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to absorb only a small amount of O$_2$ to purify an airstream, you should look up [gettering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter). Titanium metal is one of the most popular if you are willing to heat.

If you are looking to oxidize lots of material, I would look up common [reducing agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reducing_agent) that are relevant to you in terms of cost, abundance, and toxicity.